# How to get PHP parameter name from zend_arg_info

Tags: php, c

**PHP Example**

```
<?php

$id = 1;
$good = 'variable';
output_var_name($id); // Output string "id" , just variable name
output_var_name($good); // Output string "good"
```

**C/C++**

```
PHP_FUNCTION(output_var_name)
{
zend_arg_info *cur_arg_info = &CG(active_op_array)->arg_info[0];
php_printf("%s\n", cur_arg_info->name);
}
```

The above c/c++ code may be wrong, I hope you can understand what I mean.
My English is not good, but I hope to get your help! Thanks